# Google analytics in local intraweb

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, offline, intranet, matomo

I want to use Google analytics offline to measure usage on a local intranet. Is it possible to use Google analytics offline?

Answer (score 1):

No, not really.

If you use the Measurement Protocol with Analytics you can specify a time offset of up to four hours with your request - that's for mobile devices that might be temporarily offline.

But eventually the data has to be sent to the Google Server for processing, there is no standalone version that you can install at home (not anymore that is, GA was developed on the basis of urchin and for some time collected compatible data).

So, while it is possible to use GA in intranets it is not possible to use it offline (i.e. without connection to the Google servers).

Answer (score 0):

Try [Piwiki, an open-source alternative](http://piwik.org/) which you can install on a server inside your firewall.